# ParseQuery to retrieve string by objectId in Parse Database

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, textview

I have created a class "Topics" in parse database and I'm able to retrieve it to textview.

I have more than one textView so I don't want to repeat the same code.

How to retrieve a string for example if it's objectID is "fdjk"
for example I want it to work this way

```
if(objectId == fdjk){
 String subTopicName = arg0.getString("class_1");
 textView.setText("" + subTopicName);
}
 else if(objectId == fdjkk){
 String subTopicName1 = arg0.getString("class_1");
 textView1.setText("" + subTopicName1);
}
```

The following code works single object

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query=ParseQuery.getQuery("Topics");
query.getInBackground("fRGt3oz8af", new GetCallback<ParseObject>(){

    @Override
    public void done(ParseObject arg0, ParseException arg1) {

        if (arg1==null)
        {
                subTopicName = arg0.getString("class_1");
                textView.setText("" + subTopicName);
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }

        else
        {
            Log.d("topic", "Error: " + arg1.getMessage());
        }
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the objectId via

```
myParseObject.getObjectId()
```

Or maybe you should to a findInBackground so you can hace the full list of objects